# What version of Integration Services do we roll?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've been handed a SQL Server 2019 which should have CU15 installed. It has Integration Services installed and we use it for running SSIS jobs.

Looking at the assemblies on the disk we see a lot of this file version

```
2019.150.2000.5
```

So, I went over to this nice web page [KB4518398 - SQL Server 2019 build versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4518398-sql-server-2019-build-versions-782ed548-1cd8-b5c3-a566-8b4f9e20293a) and looking into the different file versions on specific assemblies.

Specifically I can see that we have a crash in `odbcdest.dll` and so I've concluded the the file version of this file (located in `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\PipelineComponents\` which is the 64-bit compiled version of that assembly) is also

```
2019.150.2000.5
```

which at least is logical.

But looking at the page from Microsoft referred in this question there have been a lot of updates in the different CU:s from the release of the RTM version. I've put together this list of all changes to odbcdest.dll from that page:

```
RTM/CU  Date        Version             Size    Link
------  -----       -------             ----    -------
RTM     2019-11-04  2019.150.2000.5
CU01    2020-01-07  2019.150.4003.23    376424  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4527376-cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2019-a8dae09e-96b5-9f13-9092-977341fafe17
CU02    2020-02-03  2019.150.4013.40    369752  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4536075-cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2019-1c344add-96bd-0810-433e-f7f9326c393c#file
CU03    2020-03-12  2019.150.4023.6     369544  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538853-cumulative-update-3-for-sql-server-2019-04829099-2b9f-863b-c8c1-aa82306a1ff4
CU04    2020-03-14  2019.150.4033.1     369752  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4548597-cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2019-4b7b7c3f-0f14-3a9a-185c-3f973dabfe52
CU05    2020-06-10  2019.150.4043.16    316296  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4552255-cumulative-update-5-for-sql-server-2019-084c602b-dc4a-d599-c857-5f18cec950fa
CU06    2020-07-25  2019.150.4053.23    316304  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4563110-cumulative-update-6-for-sql-server-2019-757cb0fa-56ff-c6e4-d56b-a695b7fdc64e
CU07    2020-08-15  2019.150.4063.15    369552  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4570012-cumulative-update-7-for-sql-server-2019-87ea390d-0def-6173-efd2-f6be8549d77d#bkmk_13585628
CU08    2020-09-13  2019.150.4073.23    316296  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4577194-cumulative-update-8-for-sql-server-2019-ed7f79d9-a3f0-a5c2-0bef-d0b7961d2d72
CU09    2021-01-25  2019.150.4102.2     369552  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5000642-cumulative-update-9-for-sql-server-2019-97ad5c3e-e002-4b6d-b566-698bf70ca44a#bkmk_13607161
CU10    2021-03-25  2019.150.4123.1     316304  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5001090-cumulative-update-10-for-sql-server-2019-b6b696ec-6598-48d9-80ee-f1b85d7a508b
CU11    2021-05-27  2019.150.4138.2     316296  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5003249-cumulative-update-11-for-sql-server-2019-657b2977-a0f1-4e1f-8b93-8c2ca8b6bef5
CU12    2021-07-19  2019.150.4153.1     316296  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004524-cumulative-update-12-for-sql-server-2019-45b2d82a-c7d0-4eb8-aa17-d4bad4059987
CU13    2021-09-23  2019.150.4178.1     369552  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5005679-cumulative-update-13-for-sql-server-2019-5c1be850-460a-4be4-a569-fe11f0adc535#bkmk_13981081
CU14    2021-11-03  2019.150.4188.2     316320  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5007182-cumulative-update-14-for-sql-server-2019-67b00a61-4f30-4a36-a5db-b506c47e563b#bkmk_14253624
CU15    2022-01-22  2019.150.4198.2     369544  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5008996-cumulative-update-15-for-sql-server-2019-4b6a8ee9-1c61-482d-914f-36e429901fb6
CU16    2022-04-11  2019.150.4223.1     317352  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5011644-cumulative-update-16-for-sql-server-2019-74377be1-4340-4445-93a7-ff843d346896
```

So, obviously Microsoft has done some working during the time from the RTM release.

Now, to my question.

If CU15 was installed why is the file version of this assembly still reporting the file version of the RTM?

It seems to me that that assembly has not been updated att all despite that CU15 should have been installed.

If we install CU16 would that upgrade Integration Services files? I would then expect `2019.150.4223.1` as the file version of `odbcdest.dll`

Below are an error from the event log that seems to indicate a real problem.

```
Fault bucket 1530726703783532086, type 5
Event Name: SQLException64
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: ISServerExec.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 0000000000000000
P4: OdbcDest.dll
P5: 2019.150.2000.5
P6: 000000005D8A80CE
P7: -1073741819
P8: 000000000001C8EB
P9: 0000000000000000
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared\ErrorDumps\ISServer_2774_92f5b77a-8b53-4703-ae89-d252652ca787_0.mdmp
\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared\ErrorDumps\ISServer_2774_92f5b77a-8b53-4703-ae89-d252652ca787_0.mdmp
\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared\ErrorDumps\ISServer_2774_92f5b77a-8b53-4703-ae89-d252652ca787_0.tmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER5DF5.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER5E15.tmp.xml

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_ISServerExec.exe_182514701e9ac3cc1cb72270426a8a84197f3757_00000000_1051626a

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 008c56b8-4633-42b4-8fb1-22555163e580
Report Status: 2147487744
Hashed bucket: 1a4563239b9578ef153e3bd3b338d636
Cab Guid: 0
```

[image: Shared Features are Incompletely installed.]

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to know what version/patch level of SQL Server, I'd run the following query

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion, @@VERSION AS MyVersion;
```

- 15.0.4223.1
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16) (KB5011644) - 15.0.4223.1 (X64)   Apr 11 2022 16:24:07   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 19044: ) (Hypervisor)

The assembly reflects that patch level.

[image]

I don't have an unpatched machine handy, but I think you'd have to explicitly not upgrade your SSIS componentry

Comment: Thanks! That is a great query which results in `ProductVersion MyVersion
15.0.4198.2 Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64)   Jan 12 2022 22:30:08   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor) `.

Comment: How should I understand that? *I think you'd have to explicitly not upgrade your SSIS componentry*? I think that there is only one (1) installation of SQL Server done to this machine. The file version of the odbcdest.dll is so strange despite that the reported version installed clearly states "RTM-CU15"!

Comment: I have a reboot pending so I can't get to the screen, but in SQL Server patching screens, one of the screens asks which product(s) should be upgraded. Top section lists the database instances that can be upgraded and the bottom section will be the shared components. SSIS will be a shared components and a person would have had to have unchecked the shared components for CU-15 and only patched the database instance. Should be a quick test, download CU-15 again, and start the upgrade. If there is work to be done, it will show that shared components can be patched

Comment: Thanks!  Doing what you recommended and selecting the node `Integration Services` in the tree view over the components of the SQL Server in the *Upgrade Status* textbox it says `Incompletely installed`. It says this for all the nodes under the *Shared Features* node. However, for the node *MSSQLSERVER* the same textbox states *Installed.*.  So, I guess we are on to something? The checkboxes before the nodes *MSSQLSERVER* and *Shared Features* are both disabled but checked.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the CU15 installation window that shows the *Upgrade Status* as `Incompletely installed.`

Comment: I have no idea how they got the system into that state. However, if you click Next, it should attempt to apply CU15.